# Best C# API to create PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation

Can you recomend any PDF API for C#. Free is the best, but I don't mind paying for it.

Comment: See [Creating pdf files at runtime in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c)

Comment: I would still suggest iText# only because even after paying you dont get nested tables and many features that iText# offers.

Comment: For future references, you may want to check out [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview) as well. It provides a simple and easy-to-use API, see the [document's content model](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/help/html/Content_Model.htm).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Update:**

I'm not sure when or if the license changed for the [iText# library](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet), but it is licensed under [AGPL](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/develop/LICENSE.md) which means it must be licensed if included with a closed-source product. The question does not (currently) require free or open-source libraries. One should always investigate the license type of any library used in a project.

---

I have used [iText#](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet) with success in .NET C# 3.5; it is a port of the open source Java library for PDF generation and it's free.

There is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itextsharp/) available for iTextSharp version 5 and the [official developer documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/developers-home), as well as C# [examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples-itext5), can be found at itextpdf.com

Comment: iTextSharp is really nice to work with.

Comment: Note that iText# is licensed under the AGPL. This means that if you include it in another program, that program must also be AGPL-licensed, __even if you offer it as a website/SaaS__.

Comment: You can still get the earlier LGPL version if you want to use the library commercially. It is available on NuGet - https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp-LGPL

Comment: iTextSharp requires a paid license if you intent to use it for anything useful, and also claims to have Java dependencies on their github page.

Comment: @shezi just wanted to thank you for your comment; Many folks tend to forget about this, and use it on comercial projects. This is a good point to keep in mind! Paul Hiles also made a really good suggestion.

Comment: @shezi Woops. I made a question here on SO about iText, and as you can see, they answered me directly about the LGPL license, and how it can cause trouble on commercial projects. So, can't use that either.

Comment: Not free anymore for closed projects.

Comment: As an alternative for iTextSharp for closed code projects you can try our [C# PDF Library IronPDF](https://ironpdf.com).  It's not free, starting from $399 USD but will get you to an installed PDF solution very quickly and easily.

Answer (score 139):

I used [PdfSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/). It's free, open source and quite convenient to use, but I can't say whether it is the best or not, because I haven't really used anything else.

Comment: +1. This one has XML documentation, so I find it a lot easier to use than iTextSharp. However, I couldn't find an equivalent of iTextSharp's `PdfTextExtractor` in PdfSharp.

Comment: PdfSharp is a nice thing, it is licensed under MIT License. So you may use it for commercial purpose as well

Comment: Pdfsharp does to support right-to-left languages

Comment: is it crossplatform? anyone experienced on linux?

Comment: https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/issues/140 

I'd like to use this library in a commercial capacity without modification, but am concerned that the presence of GPLv2 licenses in the SharpZipLib directory may annul the MIT license of this project.

For example: https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/blob/master/src/PdfSharp/SharpZipLib/SharpZipBaseException.cs

Comment: @AlexanderEgorov Have you found out this?

Comment: @Arie Yes I am but may be this issue not actual any more

Comment: @AlexanderEgorov so what was the status you find out free for commercial usage?

Comment: @Arie i dont know - i have no time to research now you can follow links provided and find it out

Comment: I just switched to PDFSharp from iTextSharp and seen a 60-70% speed increase (what I was looking for.)
It did take a bit more work tha iTextSharp to get the result I was looking for, but I can see how fine-grained the PDFSharp library is.

Answer (score 8):

My work uses Winnovative's PDF generator (We've used it mainly to convert HTML to PDF, but you can generate it other ways as well)

Comment: This is no MIT licensed software package. Be aware of this when deploying.