# Open source API to Create and add dynamic data to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, api

I'm looking at a API which allows to create PDF run-time. And also it should allow to include dynamic data and tables to PDF document. I found a API called aspose.pdf API and it allows to fullfill my requirement. But it's very expensive and now i'm looking an open source PDF creator API or low cost API?
(this is for C# development)

Please help

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best C# API to create PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937797/best-c-sharp-api-to-create-pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be possible to use [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/)? Just output the data as postscript and let the program output the pdf...

I found also this: [Creating pdf files at runtime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp). Maybe it helps.

Comment: i found pdfsharp Api from that post. it suit for my development Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

How about rendering a HTML and using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to convert it to pdf?

Alternatively, you could look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/), free for Open Source projects.