# CSV to PDF file in C#

Tags: c#, csv, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert a CSV-file (comma separated string) to a PDF-file in C# using the iTextSharp library.

I would like to know if there is any other free or more efficient tool/way for this type of conversion?

Comment: Asked before, question is rather subjective.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937797/best-c-sharp-api-to-create-pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Here's an example:

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document();
string path = @"c:\file.pdf";
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance( pdfDoc, new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
pdfDoc.Open();
pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph("your data"));
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: Your example isn't clear how to format data from CSV to PDF.