# Dynamically Convert Excel File to PDF in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Dynamically, I need to send PDF as a mail attachment only after excel sheet converted into PDF.
My question is How to convert Excel sheet into pdf dynamically in SSIS.

Can any one suggest how to acheive this scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build-in task in SSIS to generate a PDF from an Excel sheet. You can either use a 3-rd party tool tool to create a pdf out of excel and use the "Execute Process task" to trigger this tool (requires that the 3rd party tool can be controlled via command line).

Or you can create a script task, in which you reference a library to create PDFs, e.g. iText# (see here: [Best C# API to create PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937797/best-c-sharp-api-to-create-pdf)). Then you can create the PDF programmatically. To access an excel with c# you probably need the help of the Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assemblies. (Both libraries also need to be installed later on the server if you deploy the SSIS)

I once had the same problem, and all the libraries out there either required to have the Microsoft Office Primary Interop Assemblies installed or were not free of charge. I found out that it was easier to use the Microsoft SQL Serer Reporting Services to create the pdf - an introduction how to do this can be found here:
http://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/generate-pdf-report-from-ssis/
But that would require that you have your base data somewhere stored in a database.

Hope this information can be helpful for your.