# The Kendo Grid is generated on page using Ajax in the background in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pdf, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid for reporting purposes for ASP.Net MVC application. It works fine.

I am not sure how to do this, any help / idea is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're going to find a solution to this problem using Kendo's PDF export functionality. I did look at this as part of a requirement for work but the functionality is too limited. We ended up using something separate for PDF generation in the end.

I'd take a look at [the PDF APIs listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937797/best-c-sharp-api-to-create-pdf) to see whether or not any of them suit your requirements.