# Need to create pdf files dynamically for each patient in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I need to create seprate pdf file for each n number of patients all together. So if anyone selects that patient in the gridview it should open that individual patient pdf. 
Please someone tell me how to approach for this.

Comment: Have you check this out ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp

Comment: I am using itextsharp as a tool. Please specify the approach to create number of pdfs at one go

Comment: When they click the get pdf button, what gets downloaded? A zip of individual pdf s for each patient? One big pdf with everything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of [iTextSharp](http://nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp) dLL that will help you to create PDF file easily

here is article and demo for this : [Creating PDF documents with iTextSharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277065/Creating-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp)

one more good eample : [Create PDF document using iTextSharp in ASP.Net 4.0 and MemoryMappedFile](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/03/07/create-pdf-document-using-itextsharp-in-asp-net-4-0-and-memorymappedfile.aspx)