# Write to txt in a 'form-like' manner

Tags: c#

I'm implementing a Windows application to make planning projects easier at my workplace and I was wondering if there's any clever way of making a txt-file nicely structured.

The application is really very simple, pretty much what it does is give the user a question which is answered in a textbox bellow. The question AND the answer are then both sent to a file but it looks very tacky.

Example:

Question?Answer!Question?Answer!

I would like it to be more like this:

**Question?**
Answer!

**Question?**
Answer!

I was also curious about other types files, is it possible to use Pdf or MS word the same way as txt?

Comment: How about using XML? Linq to XML makes it really easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `File.AppendAllLines()` and pass in the different strings as an array. They will appear as separate lines in the text file. You'll also need to add a `using System.IO` at the top of your file.

For example:

```
// Ensure file exists before we write
if (!File.Exists("<YOUR_FILE_PATH>.txt"))
{
    using (File.CreateText("<YOUR_FILE_PATH>.txt")) {}
}

File.AppendAllLines("<YOUR_FILE_PATH>.txt", new string[] {
    "Question1",
    "Answer1",
    "Question2",
    "Answer2",
    "Question3",
    "Answer3"
});
```

I hope this is what you're after - the question is a little vague.

As for Word and PDF files, this is more complex. Here's a link to a StackOverflow question about Word:

[How can a Word document be created in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412/how-can-a-word-document-be-created-in-c)

and one about PDF:

[Creating pdf files at runtime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple text file you could use

```
StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder();
fileData.AppendLine("Question: blah! blah! blah! blah!");
fileData.AppendLine("Answer: blah! blah! blah! blah!");

FileStream fs = new FileStream("yourFile.txt", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.Write(fileData.ToString());
sw.Flush();
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
```

But of course it won't give you that **bold** question flavor, for that you would have to use something else,

like **MS Word** interop, to learn that [visit here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384).

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to mention the `String.Format` function.

suppose, you have your strings `question` and `answer`, you could do some

```
using (var stream = new StreamWriter('myfile.txt', true)) // append=true
  stream.Write(String.Format("\n{0}\n{1}\n\n{2}\n", 
                             question, 
                             new String('=',question.Length), 
                             answer);
```

to get a text file like

```
Question 1
==========
Answer

Second Question
===============
Answer
```

You might also want to use `String.Trim()` on `question` to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace (`question = question.Trim()`), so the "underline" effect looks nicely.