# Creating PDF file in C++/CLI

Tags: pdf, c++-cli

How can I create PDF file and write on it some data using C++/CLI ? Do I need external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need an external library. Try searching for "write PDF from C#", and use that from C++/CLI. Here's one question I found: [Creating pdf files at runtime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp).