# How to implement pdf in asp.net using C# or JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf-generation

I am creating a project on  online movie ticket booking. Now I want to create a pdf file of ticket. How to create or generate a pdf file.

Comment: Related, poss duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

To generate pdf go for below code

```
        Document document = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document , new FileStream(@"C:\YourPdf.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document .Open();
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Hi, \n This is my pdf file");
        document .Add(paragraph);
        document .Close();
```

For more information :-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-create-pdf-document-in-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp-using-itextsharp-1023.aspx

Comment: You may want to add information about the third party library the OP will need in order to use this code.

Comment: yes @DaveParsons I have added link for more info

Answer (score -1):

I've used [PDF4Net](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) in the past, it's very easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

In addition I have used [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=24&Itemid=35) and it's very simple and intuitive!
Cheers