# Convert hex string to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf-generation

I have a string like `0x255044462D312E330D0A312030206F626A0D0` and I've tried to convert it to a `PDF`.

**Code:**

```
var inputStr="my hex string";
pdfFile = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputStr).ToArray();
return new FileContentResult(pdfFile, "application/pdf");
```

It's not working ( "Failed to load PDF document" is the message I get ). What am I doing wrong? I've also tried to change `response`:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", pdfFile.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=sample.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(pdfFile);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

**Update**

I don't know how the string was initially encoded

**Update 2**

So I'm receiving "-2" because of someone who thought this questions is a duplicate ( he deteled his answer by the way ) ? Thank you

Comment: What's not working? What are error(s) if there are any?

Comment: Do you know how the string was encoded?

Comment: No. I don't have any informations about the initial encoding. I get "Failed to load PDF document". I've updated my question

Comment: Why '-1'? No. It's not. I want it as PDF, not only as a byte[].

Comment: Ultimately this is how to convert a hex string to a byte array http://stackoverflow.com/q/311165/231316

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your hex string is actually a **valid pdf file** you need to convert it into a byte array like this:

```
var inputStr = "0x255044462D312E330D0A312030206F626A0D0";
var hex = inputStr.Substring(2);

int NumberChars = hex.Length / 2;
byte[] pdfFile = new byte[NumberChars];
using (var sr = new StringReader(hex))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
        pdfFile[i] = Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2]{(char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read()}), 16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some kind of API to create a PDF document. PDF files are complicated file formats and what you have created is basically just a text file.

I'm assuming the error "Failed to load PDF document" is from whatever software is trying to open the PDF file. It is getting the mime header that you have specified saying it is a pdf file but when it looks it doesn't find a pdf file, just a text file.

As an example of this try changing the mime type from "application/pdf" to "text/plain" and you should find it will give you a text file with your input text in it.

Although closed as off topic [Creating pdf files at runtime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp) has discussions on APIs that can be used to create PDFs.