# Generate PDF from Dynamic data - Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm trying to develop a Windows 8.1 store app that can generate pdf report from the application data (Local Sqlite data in my case.). I've searched all over the internet to get a free library that can be used to generate pdf from the store app. But I might miss someone, this is why asking the experts in this field.

Apart from Syncfusion ,what are the available paid libraries can (cheaper than syncfusion) be used to generate pdf.

Note: Please do not refer ItextSharp or something similar that works only on C# console application.

Comment: http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/04/23/annotating-pdf-documents-in-a-windows-8-store-app.aspx. While it doesn't answer your question exactly, I believe the listed SDKs do support creating PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, you can send data via post:
https://www.mashape.com/yogthos/instant-pdf#!documentation

Comment: None of this supports WinRT I guess.

Comment: Any of this help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp

Comment: I don't know, some of the libraries are based on .NET framework, still can't able to run it from a windows 8.1 store app.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to QuickPDF 
First to add QuickPDFAX0726.dll to your project 

C# Code 
using QuickPDF64AX0813;

QuickPDF64AX0813.PDFLibrary qp = new PDFLibrary();
qp.ClearFileList("Main");
qp.AddToFileList("Main", Path + FileName + ".pdf");
qp.MergeFileList("Main", Path + StrNewFileName + ".pdf");
```