# How can I create a dynamic pdf with c#

Tags: c#, html, email, pdf

I have a conception problem and before coding I would like your help.

My goal is to create an app that call an api, gather the data, analyze it, create a report from it and lastly send it by email.

I managed to get the data (as json) with c#, to deserialize it and to make my analysis.

I would like to know what would be the best way to create a nice pdf with the data. My goal would therefore to create for example an html template, that every time I call out my api it modify the content of the template and generate from the html a pdf.

If I think about html it is because I know that I can do my html exactly as I am please, but the problem is the conversion to pdf that sometimes destroy a bit the style.

I know that with visual code I can create html pages, and I would like to know if I can modify the content from a c# page if it is the same project.

If not, can you recommend anything in order for me to do a pdf exactly as I am please with the dynamic content

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating pdf files at runtime in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465433/creating-pdf-files-at-runtime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I have used iTextSharp and HiQPdf for the same purpose. Just google them and you will find lots of stuff.

Comment: Another one 'aspose'

Comment: Look at this question for "HTML to PDF" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25164257/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp